# Add field_with_error to dynamically named form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a form for edit a record of Item model **WITHOUT showing id of Item** on html.
To identify Item record, I use **id_sub** column.
(**id_sub** is 10 characters string.)

#### models/item.rb

```
def item
  # ---------- columns ----------
  # id     : integer, primary key
  # id_sub : string
  # name   : string
end
```

Because I don't want to show **Item's id**, I use **id_sub** for fields and parameters.

This works fine.
However, when it has errors, **field_with_error** doesn't be added to form.

It is because Rails can't find field dynamically named, I think.
Are there ways to have Rails to find dynamically named field?
Or does only way is using JavaScript for it?

#### controllers/items_controller.rb

```
def update_all
  @errors = []
  @items = params[:item].map do |id_sub, item_params|
    item = Item.find_by(id_sub: id_sub)
    if item && !item.update(name: item_params[:name])
      @errors << item.errors
    end
    item
  end

  if @errors.blank?
    redirect_to :edit_all_items
  else
    render :edit_all
  end
end
```

#### views/items/edit_all.html.haml

```
= form_tag update_all_items_path, method: :patch do
  - @items.each do |item|
      = fields_for 'items[]', item do |f|

        -# --- Dynamically named field below. ---
        = text_field_tag "items[#{item.id_sub}][name]"
        = submit_tag
```

Any help is going to be appreciated. :)

Comment: I don't see anything in your edit.html.haml that will display the errors. Because of this,  I can only guess what you meant by "when it has errors, field_with_error doesn't be added to form.". Do you have other view files that display the errors? Please add that to your question as well.

Comment: I think ActionView::Base class add <div class="field_with_errors"> tag for outside of field for having error attribute. Isn't that so?

Comment: Your `edit_all.html.haml` doesn't include `<div class="field_with_errors">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form builder object `f`. It will generate the `div class="field_with_error">` automatically per `tag` called (i.e. `f.text_field`, `f.number_field`).

For your custom id, you will need to pass `include_id: false` in `fields_for`, and add your own `hidden_field` `id_sub`.

```
- @items.each do |item|
  = fields_for 'items[]', item, include_id: false do |f|
    -# --- Dynamically named field below. ---
    = f.hidden_field :id_sub, value: f.object.id_sub
    = f.text_field name.to_sym
    = f.submit
```

You will need to update your controller as well, because you should not associate the index of `items[]` as the primary key of the Item model.

```
def update_all
  @items = params[:item].map do |index, item_params|
    Item.find_by(id_sub: item_params[:id_sub]).update(item_params)
  end
  # @items will already contain the error messages at this point should there be errors,
  # Errors will then be shown in the view accordingly
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to which field have the error. Ex) https://gyazo.com/a30dc8d94450747565a2e0616a7c1820

Comment: OMG! Very sorry, but this code doesn't remove id. "22" in image below url is id. I want to use id_sub in place of id. Would u mind tell me any idea? 
https://gyazo.com/07d95c61ed32d1d257aff5d44fcaeded

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.
This option was required.

> index: item.id_sub

```
- @items.each do |item|
  = fields_for 'items[]', item, index: item.id_sub, include_id: false do |f|
    -# --- Dynamically named field below. ---
    = f.hidden_field :id_sub, value: f.object.id_sub
    = f.text_field name.to_sym
    = f.submit
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Jay-ArPolidario !

Comment: No prob! Glad to help :)